# How to redirect a directory in Nginx server

Tags: nginx, redirect

i have tried redirecting a file name it worked in Nginx but i tried the same in redirecting a folder or directory its not working. Please help me out in this as i was new to Nginx server.

I have tired like this

```
if ($request_uri ~ "/old-folder/") {
            rewrite ^ /current-folder/ permanent;
      }
```

Comment: try `location ^~ /old-folder/ { rewrite ^ /current-folder permanent; }`

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
location ~/old-folder {
       rewrite /current-folder permanent;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @NooBskie i have tried that too its not working :(